# Gatsby wtih react-boilerplate

Tags: heroku, gatsby, react-boilerplate

I have React application built using react-boilerplate as a base. I am now looking to add a /blog route which is statically delivered using Gatsby. I tried to look at how I would be able to do this, but cant see how react-router can potentially handover the control to the Gatsby blog when user visits /blog on my site.

Any pointers of how this can be done would be helpful.

Thanks,
RP